# Meteor Cordova iOS unknown error. Audience Network advertising is not displayed

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, meteor, facebook-audience-network

I’m using Meteor with Cordova for iOS app and I got the unknown error in the XCode console:

```
FacebookAds, onAdFailLoad, {'adNetwork':'FacebookAds','adType':'banner','adEvent':'onAdFailLoad','error':1013,'reason':''}
```

What does it mean ???